# X forwarding broken after using Xvfb

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding, xvfb

I used Xvfb to create a fake desktop to run programs with graphical interface on a Debian pc without display for testing purposes.

After completing these tests, I wanted to revert back to the "old" configuration where ssh -Y (or -X) forwards graphics. However I'm encountering some issues. The pc now has a display attached that works as intended.

When I try to start any program that requires x forwarding I get something like this (this is the error I get when I start xeyes)

```
Error: Can't open display:
```

However, in any case I can use the terminal as intended. Here are some (hopefully) useful informations and failed attempts.

1. if I start an ssh session with

   ssh -Y user@ip

and then do echo $DISPLAY I get a blank line. The same happens if I use the pc from console and start an ssh session to localhost. The same also happens if I use the -X flag. However if I do echo $DISPLAY from console I get a non-blank answer.

2. I changed X11Forwarding and X11UseLocalhost to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config as suggested in some answers.
3. Killing the Xvfb process didn't solve the problem. Also, uninstalling the package didn't work.

Any suggestions or fixes that I can try?